# MacBook Pro 2018 can't use 80Mhz wifi channel

Tags: wifi

I have a WiFi AC access point (my access point is linux pc + qca9882 + manually configured hostapd), which works on 153/80Mhz channel. However my MacBook connectes to this access point it switches between 20Mhz/80Mhz channel bandwidth several times and then stops on 20Mhz.

RSSI/Noize is -47dBm/-97dBm, there is no other 5Ghz stations according to the WiFi Explorer.

How can I find out why my MacBook can't use 80mhz?

Comment: What make and model is the WiFi Access point?

Comment: Can't you select the wifi to run at a certain frequency in the router settings, rather than auto 20/80MHz? Also you can see the wifi specs for MacBook Pro 2018 here: https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/deployment-reference-macos/apdd3e47748d/web

Comment: my access point is linux pc + qca9882 + manually configured hostapd

Comment: It seems that I can't force 80MHz channel on router